# Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2(\ln x - \ln (x-1)) - x = 1/2$

Tags: limits

I am trying to calculate this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2(\ln x-\ln (x-1))-x$$
The answer is $1/2$ but I am trying to verify this through proper means. I have tried L'Hospital's Rule by factoring out an $x$ and putting that as $\frac{1}{x}$ in the denominator (indeterminate form) but it becomes hopeless afterwards. Also I am a little hesitant about series involving the natural log because of restricted interval of convergence as $x$ is going to infinity. Is there a different approach how to do evaluate this limit? Thanks.

Comment: the searched Limit should be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. I know that, it is in my post! I want to verify this through mathematical means

Comment: use the rules of L'Hospital

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} [ x^2(\ln x-\ln (x-1))-x]&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle\ln x-\ln (x-1)-\frac{1}{x}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\displaystyle\frac{-2}{x^3}}\quad (\text{ L'Hopital Rule})\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle\frac{-1}{x^2(x-1)}}{\displaystyle\frac{-2}{x^3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, instead of putting $1/x$ in the denominator, you put $1/x^2$ in the denominator so that the $ln$ terms have no longer an $x$ upfront and thus, their derivatives become rational functions!. Excellent and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $1/x=h$ to get $$-\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln(1-h)+h}{h^2}$$

Now either use Taylor Expansion or L'Hospital

or See the third Question of [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
 \lim_{x \to \infty}x^2(\ln x-\ln (x-1))-x
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} (-x^2(\ln (1-1/x))-x)\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0} (-\frac1{y^2}(\ln (1-y))-\frac1{y})\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0} (-\frac1{y^2}((y+\frac{y^2}{2}+O(\frac1{y^3}))-\frac1{y})\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0} ((\frac1{y}+\frac{1}{2}+O(\frac1{y}))-\frac1{y})\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0} (\frac{1}{2}+O(\frac1{y}))\\
&=\frac12\\
\end{array}
$

You could also write
$(-\frac1{y^2}(\ln (1-y))-\frac1{y})
=-\frac{\ln (1-y)+y}{y^2}
$
and use
L'Hopital.

Answer (score 0):

Using fact that
$$\ln (1+u)=u-\frac {u^2}{2}(1+\epsilon (u)) $$ with $\lim_0 \epsilon (u)=0$,
we get
$$x^2 \ln (\frac{x}{x-1})-x=$$

$$x^2\ln(1+\frac {1}{x-1})-x =$$
$$=x^2 (\frac {1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2 (x-1)^2} (1+\epsilon (x)) -x$$
with $\lim_{+\infty}\epsilon (x)=0$,
$$=\frac {x}{x-1}-\frac {x^2}{2 (x-1)^2}\left(1+\epsilon (x)\right) $$

the limit is
$$1-\frac {1}{2}=\frac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln x - \ln(x-1)=\ln\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x^3}+\cdots, $$
so $$x^2(\ln x - \ln(x-1))-x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x}+\cdots$$
and thus $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}[x^2(\ln x - \ln(x-1))-x]=\frac{1}{2}.$$